# Avoid or minimize the chance of AWS EC2 Spot instance reclaiming

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I have to use EC2 for some computation. I have come to know about EC2 spot instances that they are at max 90% less in price as compared to on-demand instances. But one disadvantage is that spot instances can be reclaimed any time that may caue to loose data or failure of running job.

To avoid this change, how can I minimize the chance of reclaiming ? What if I give a price rate near to on-demand ? Will it minimize the chance ?

I have visited few [pages](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5774477/on-amazon-ec2-will-the-spot-instance-price-ever-be-higher-than-the-on-demand-pr) also but need little more guide

Comment: The answer you linked to is out of date information, the [EC2 Spot Market rules have changed since then](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/compute/new-amazon-ec2-spot-pricing/).  The only real answer to handling spot instances is to be prepared for them to go away by arching work often, and respond to the two minute warning appropriately.

Comment: I think you should use spot instances for non-prod environments and mix between spot and on-demand.